How to combine Minimal API's Pipeline Branching with MapGet syntax?
Say I want to have 2 endpoints, /a and /b, while also utilizing the pipeline branching for both of those endpoints, for adding custom middleware for them.
The following code does not work:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

var a = "/a";
var b = "/b";

app.Map(a, true, branch =>
{
    branch.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Test", "a");
        return next(context);
    });
});

app.Map(b, true, branch =>
{
    branch.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Test", "b");
        return next(context);
    });
});

app.MapGet(a, () => "hello from a!");
app.MapGet(b, () => "hello from b!");

app.Run();

Calling /a fails with:
System.InvalidOperationException: The request reached the end of the pipeline without executing the endpoint: 'HTTP: GET /a'. Please register the EndpointMiddleware using 'IApplicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(...)' if using routing.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.<>c.<Build>b__25_0(HttpContext context)
   at Program.<>c.<<Main>$>b__0_4(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) in C:\Users\...\RiderProjects\MinimalApiSample\MinimalApiSample\Program.cs:line 15
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

But I can't figure out, where to put UseEndpoints and why do I need it after adding custom app.Map(... calls? I'm also not putting UseRouting anywhere because I tried it right before the first app.Map(... but it didn't change the outcome and apparently it's not required in Minimal API at all.

Use UseWhen:

Conditionally creates a branch in the request pipeline that is rejoined to the main pipeline.

app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path == a, ab => ab.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Test", "a");
    return next(context);
}));

//... the same for the b

app.MapGet(a, () => "hello from a!");

Map on the other hand creates just a separate branch:

Branches the request pipeline based on matches of the given request path. If the request path starts with the given path, the branch is executed.

Also see the Branch the middleware pipeline section of the docs.
UPD
if you need the separate branch then you can just build it fully. For example for /b:
app.Map(b, true, branch =>
{
    branch.Use((context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Test", "b");
        return next(context);
    });
    branch.UseRouting();
    branch.UseEndpoints(rb => rb.MapGet(b, () => "hello from b!"));
});


What if I want to use multiple middlewares for a certain branch? Not sure how would that look like. So for example, for a first one, I want smth like app.UseMiddleware<Middleware1>().UseMiddleware<Middleware2>() and for second I want app.UseMiddleware<Middleware3>().UseMiddleware<Middleware4>()?

But what if I don't want those 2 branches to rejoin in the end?

@nix what is the desired output when calling /a? app.MapGet(a, () => "hello from a!"); is declared in the "main" branch, without rejoining it this code is basically useless.

The result should be whatever the MapGet executes and returns, but the pipelines are supposed to be different.

Oh, I see. Is there a way to use MapGet without rejoining? I could simulate its behavior with a custom middleware in the end of the branched pipeline, but that wouldn't allow me to use AllowAnonymous, which is what I ultimately need.

@nix that does not work this way. As I wrote in the update in the comment - your MapGet are part of the "main branch".

@nix updated the answer a bit, but it seems to be a XY problem. "but that wouldn't allow me to use AllowAnonymous, which is what I ultimately need" - can you please elaborate (possibly a separate question will be needed)

You can use MapWhen. Below is your example with applied corrections:
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path == a, branch =>
{
    branch.Run(context =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Test", "a");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});

app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path == b, branch =>
{
    branch.Run(context =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Test", "b");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
});


This is basically my answer =)
